# call controller from itemController

Tags: ember.js

If I have an itemController defined like this:

```
{{#each item in items itemController="item"}}
  {{#with item}}
    <tr>
      <td class="check">
        <label {{action  selectItem this bubbles="false"}}>
          {{description}}
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{/with}}
```

The action above will be routed to the itemController.

Is there anyway to override this behaviour and to the main controller?

Comment: This is probably resolved now, but in the case it is not, I think there is a `parentController` property on the itemController, perhaps you could use it as the target of the action ? (you should remove the {{with}} because it switches context.